# Custom ListView with Date as SectionHeader (Used custom SimpleCursorAdapter)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-custom-view

I want to  display ListView with Date as SectionHeader.

**What i have :**
  I am displaying ListView from sqlite database using custom SimpleCursorAdapter.

My Custom SimpleCursorAdapter is :

```java
public class DomainAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
private Cursor dataCursor;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public DomainAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor dataCursor, String[] from,
        int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, dataCursor, from, to);
        this.dataCursor = dataCursor;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);//Task Title
        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label2);//Task Date
        holder.img =   (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_icon);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    int title = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("title"); 
    String task_title = dataCursor.getString(title);

    int title_date = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("day"); 
    String task_day = dataCursor.getString(title_date);

    int description_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("priority"); 
    int priority = dataCursor.getInt(description_index);

    holder.text1.setText(task_title);
    holder.text2.setText(task_day);

    if(priority==1) holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.redbutton);
    else if(priority==2) holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluebutton);
    else if(priority==3)holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton);
    else holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.redbuttonchecked);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    ImageView img;
}
}
```

**Google Results so far :**

[MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)

[Jeff Sharkey](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/)

[Amazing ListView](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841078/section-header-in-listview-not-show-correctly)

**Problem :** I want to display listview with Date as section headers. Ofcourse Date values come from sqlite database.

Can anyone please guide me how can i achieve this task.

Or Provide me a Sample Code or Exact(like) Code related to the same.

**Edited** According to Graham Borald's Answer (This works fine. However it was a quick fix.)

```java
public class DomainAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    private Cursor dataCursor;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public DomainAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor dataCursor, String[] from,
            int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, dataCursor, from, to);
            this.dataCursor = dataCursor;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);//Task Title
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label2);//Task Date
            holder.img =   (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskImage);

            holder.sec_hr=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sec_header);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int title = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("title"); 
        String task_title = dataCursor.getString(title);

        int title_date = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("due_date"); 
        String task_day = dataCursor.getString(title_date);

        int description_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("priority"); 
        int priority = dataCursor.getInt(description_index);

        String prevDate = null;

        if (dataCursor.getPosition() > 0 && dataCursor.moveToPrevious()) {
            prevDate = dataCursor.getString(title_date);
            dataCursor.moveToNext();
        }


        if(task_day.equals(prevDate))
        {
            holder.sec_hr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.sec_hr.setText(task_day);
            holder.sec_hr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.text1.setText(task_title);
        holder.text2.setText(task_day);

        if(priority==1) holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.redbutton);
        else if(priority==2) holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluebutton);
        else if(priority==3)holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton);
        else holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.redbuttonchecked);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
        TextView sec_hr;
        ImageView img;
    }
}
```

**Edited** According to CommonsWare's Answer

```java
public class DomainAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
        private Cursor dataCursor;
        private TodoDbAdapter adapter;

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        boolean header;
      String last_day;
      public DomainAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor dataCursor, String[] from,
        int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, dataCursor, from, to);
        this.dataCursor = dataCursor;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        header=true;
        adapter=new TodoDbAdapter(context);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    TitleHolder title_holder = null;

    if(getItemViewType(position)==1)
    {
        //convertView= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_row, parent, false);

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);//Task Title
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label2);//Task Date
            holder.img =   (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int title = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("title"); 
        String task_title = dataCursor.getString(title);

        int title_date = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("day"); 
        String task_day = dataCursor.getString(title_date);

        int description_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("priority"); 
        int priority = dataCursor.getInt(description_index);

        holder.text1.setText(task_title);
        holder.text2.setText(task_day);

        if(priority==1) holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.redbutton);
        else if(priority==2) holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluebutton);
        else if(priority==3)holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton);
        else holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.redbuttonchecked);
    }
    else
    {

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.section_header, null);

            title_holder = new TitleHolder();
            title_holder.datee = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sec_header);//Task Title

            convertView.setTag(title_holder);
        }
        else 
        {
            title_holder = (TitleHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        int title_date = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("day"); 
        String task_day = dataCursor.getString(title_date);

        title_holder.datee.setText(task_day);
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    ImageView img;
}

 static class TitleHolder{
    TextView datee;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataCursor.getCount()+1; //just for testing i took no. of headers=1
}


@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    **Long id=dataCursor.getLong(position);**
    Cursor date=adapter.fetchTodo(id);
    int title_date = date.getColumnIndex("day"); 
        String task_day = date.getString(title_date);
        Log.i("tag",task_day);

    if(last_day.equals(task_day))
        return 1;//Display Actual Row
    else
    {
        last_day=task_day;//Displaying Header
        return 0;
    }

}

/*
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View view;

    if(getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition())==1)
        view= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_row, parent, false);
    else
        view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.section_header,parent, false);

    return view;

}

@Override
public void bindView(View convertView, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    long id = cursor.getPosition();

}*/
}
```

I am getting *Null Pointer Exception* at line : `Cursor date=adapter.fetchTodo(id);`
Seems that Cursor is not getting any data.

Comment: https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Answer (score 55, accepted):

By far the simplest way to do this is to embed the date header view *in every item*. Then, all you need to do in `bindView` is compare the previous row's date to this row's date, and hide the date if it's the same. Something like this:

```java
    String thisDate = cursor.getString(dateIndex);
    String prevDate = null;

    // get previous item's date, for comparison
    if (cursor.getPosition() > 0 && cursor.moveToPrevious()) {
        prevDate = cursor.getString(dateIndex);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    // enable section heading if it's the first one, or 
    // different from the previous one
    if (prevDate == null || !prevDate.equals(thisDate)) {
        dateSectionHeaderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        dateSectionHeaderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick fix.This is working. But i want to go as per CommonsWare's answer. Can you please help in implementing that ?

Comment: I don't regard this as being a quick fix. I think it's a very neat, compact and efficient solution to the problem. I've used exactly this approach in production code, and it gives extremely good results. What aspect of it are you unhappy with?

Comment: Problem : when i long click on the first item(which also contains header) whole view of that item gets yellow colored.I dont want that.

Comment: I know it can be done by customizing the color of list item when clicked or focused. But i dont want to do that

Comment: I also think that Graham's solution is a good one (+1 for you). It involves less code and is more maintainable. And as you say, you can customize the color of the list item when clicked on pretty easily. What's not to like?

Comment: This works when scrolling down but when I scroll back up the headers get all mixed up.

Comment: Isn't another disadvantage that clicking on a dated section header result in call to onOptionsItemSelected()? IE clicking on a date heading will result in the same action as clicking on the row below the date.

Comment: @DonalRafferty True, have you resolved this problem?

Comment: Cyril Mottier has an improved version of this with a detailed write-up at http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/ I think the line which has "cursor.moveToPosition(position - 1);" solves the issue of scrolling back up.

Comment: This is the smartest, simplest, yet most efficient solution I have ever found after searching for a couple of days.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone please guide me how can i achieve this task.

With substantial pain.

You will need to create your own subclass of `CursorAdapter` (or possibly `SimpleCursorAdapter`). In that subclass, you will need to calculate the number of header rows and adjust `getCount()` to match. You will need to have `getViewTypeCount()` return the right number. You will need to identify the positions of those header rows and adjust `getItemViewType()`, `newView()`, and `bindView()` to deal with your header rows, adjusting the `position` value for detail rows to take into account the number of headers that are ahead of that row, so you get the right `Cursor` position to work with. There may need to be other adjustments as well, but those are fairly certain.

If nobody beats me to it, I will probably write one of these in the next year, once it's needed for a project of mine.

Comment: Thanks for your superb response. Really appreciate your answer and effort. But i want to confirm what i have understood.

Comment: 1. getCount() should return number of items(rows) or number of total items(rows+header) ?

Comment: @Kartik: rows+headers. More accurately, `getCount()` returns the number of rows that should be in the `ListView`, which bears some resemblance to the number of "rows" in your `Cursor`, but in your case also needs to take into account any headers or other rows you are adding to the mix.

Comment: @CommonsWare : thanks alot for crystal clear explanation. now 
2. getViewTypeCount() should return the number of headers !..
3. getItemViewType() how can i adjust for headers and data ?..

Comment: @Kartik: `getViewTypeCount()` returns the number of distinct types of rows you will be displaying. #3 is your job, because you are the one mandating these headers, you are the one with the business rules for where the headers should appear. Nobody on the face of the planet can help you with that.

Comment: @CommonsWare : 4. newView() which View i should return ? Row 1 or row 2 ?

Comment: @Kartik: How should I know? `newView()` needs to generate whatever `View` is appropriate for the requested `ListView` position. Only you know what that is.

Answer (score 2):

it is very simple for implementation:

```
public class ChatAdapter extends NoteBaseAdapter {

private Cursor mCursor;

/**
 * List of notes to showToast
 */

public int getCount() {
    int count = 0;
    if (mCursor != null)
        count = mCursor.getCount();
    return count;
}

public Comment getItem(int position) {
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    Comment comment = Comment.fromCursor(mCursor);
    return comment;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Comment comment = getItem(position);

    CommentCell cellView = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        cellView = new CommentCell(parent.getContext());
        cellView.setup(elementsColor, backgroundColor);
    } else
        cellView = (CommentCell) convertView;

    cellView.setComment(comment);

    boolean showHeader = false;
    String currentDate = null;

    if (position > 0 && position < getCount()) {

        int previousPosition = position - 1;
        Comment previousComment = getItem(previousPosition);

        currentDate = comment.headerDate();
        String previousDate = previousComment.headerDate();

        showHeader = !currentDate.equalsIgnoreCase(previousDate);
    } else {
        showHeader = true;
        currentDate = comment.headerDate();
    }

    cellView.showHeader(showHeader, currentDate);

    return cellView;
}

public void update(long itemUniqueId) {
    mCursor = Comment.fetchResultCursor(itemUniqueId);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and show/hide header in custom CommentCell view:

```
  public void showHeader(boolean show, String currentDate) {
    if (show) {
        headerTextview.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        headerTextview.setText(currentDate);
    } else {
        headerTextview.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}
```

create string date:

```
public String headerDate() {
    String createDateStr = null;
    if (createDate != Consts.NONE_LONG)
        createDateStr = TimeUtil.dateToString("dd MMMM", new Date(createDate));
    return createDateStr;
}

public static String dateToString(String format, Date date) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault());
    String text = dateFormat.format(date);
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution. It's a lot of code.