# How do I implement a sectioned list in Android?

Tags: android, listview, indexer

I have a search feature which displays results in a ListView. I'm finding it difficult to implement an alphabetical sectioned list. Please give me idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find bunch of this topic using Google. Here some best tutorial in my opinion. Basically you use `SectionIndexer` to create an index and show(or hide) view in `getView` method of your adapter.

1, [ListView Tips & Tricks #2: Sectioning your ListView](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=440) by Cyril Mottier.

2, [Pinned Header ListView as in the Contacts app](http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/05/pinned-header-listview-as-in-contacts.html) by Peter Kuterna.

3, [IndexableListView](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView) by Daniel Nam

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261593/custom-listview-with-date-as-sectionheader-used-custom-simplecursoradapter