# Sectioned ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am an iOS developer getting familiar with Android. How can I make a sectioned list view like this table view from one of my iOS apps?
[image]

Comment: Is this helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397900/how-do-i-implement-a-sectioned-list-in-android

Comment: Or this: http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android  Or this:  http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html Or this: http://umakantpatil.com/posts/android-listview-with-separate-headers-and-images-loading-from-remote-server/ etc   You will have to do more work for your specific needs, but that should get you started.

Comment: Using a search engine, to search for `android sectioned listview`, turns up many pages, including Stack Overflow answers, blog posts, and GitHub repos.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to make a vanilla listview. (You basically create an adapter and set this adapter to a listview by doing ListView.setAdapter). For a sectioned listview, you need to do some additional work. Here You have two types of list items 1) Apps; 2) Section title. So in your adapter, you need to override getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount in addition to getView.

Here's an code demo:

```
public class EnhancedListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private static final int TYPE_SECTION = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_APP  = 1;

    // since you only have 2 types
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = 2;

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            // your list object should have a getter to tell what type it is
            switch (getItem(position).getItemType()) {
                case SECTION:
                    return TYPE_TXT_OUT;
                case APP:
                    return TYPE_IMG_OUT;
                default:
                    return -1;
            }

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // this is the function you just override
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            switch (type) {
                // I assume you would provide two different row layouts for the Section type and the App type
                case TYPE_SECTION:
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section, null);
                    break;
                case TYPE_APP:
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app, null);
                    break;
            }                
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (MessageItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // do your stuffs here

    }

}
```